# why string literal cannot be Garbage Collected

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory

In general in any project we use lot of string's , as

```
String name="John"; ...etc
```

But According to JVM String literal cannot be GC'd
even though we are not having use with name after sometime ie

```
name = null;
```

that object cannot be GC'd
  Why it is Designed in that way which may lead to out of memory Problems

Comment: please provide the source of _According to JVM_

Comment: JVM optimzes stringm usage using stringpool. It will be Gc'ed but only when it is absolutely necessary, else it will be maintained in StringPool and if the same string is used for some other variable assignment, instead of creating a new string it will use the same from the string pool. +1Oleg

Comment: Your claimed requirement does not appear in either the current [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) or the current [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf).